# Cant retrieve the JSON using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My JSON:

```
{
 "operatorname": "LUKUP",
 "Schedule": {
 "channel": [
  {
  "bouquet": "Music",
  "channelgenre": "English Music",
  "prepaid_price": 15
  },
  {
   "bouquet": "News",
   "channelgenre": "English News",
   "prepaid_price": 7
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my_url,
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
         message= JSON.parse(result);
         alert(message.Schedule.channel.length);
      }
   });
```

My json is coming. First alert message is giving my JSON. When i parse that json, error is coming like

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Location: jquery.min.js.2**

I tried solving this issue. Couldnt able to figure out where it is going wrong.

Can anyone help me

Comment: That means there is error in your JSON format

Comment: i validated my json using json validator

Comment: Check `typeof result` in `success`

Comment: typeof is coming as object.

Comment: Then there is no need of parsing it to JSON. Remove `message= JSON.parse(result);`

Comment: ya it worked after i removed that line

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comas after `"prepaid_price": 15` and `"prepaid_price": 7`. You are also missing a closing `}` at the end of your JSON.

You can validate your JSON here: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

```
{
    "operatorname": "LUKUP",
    "Schedule": {
        "channel": [
            {
                "bouquet": "Music",
                "channelgenre": "English Music",
                "prepaid_price": 15
            },
            {
                "bouquet": "News",
                "channelgenre": "English News",
                "prepaid_price": 7
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataType: 'json',` in your AJAX-call, then your JSON will be parsed automatically and you don't need to call `message = JSON.parse(result);` because your result will be already an Object.

Then you can call `alert(result.Schedule.channel.length);` direct.

Your code would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: my_url,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        alert(result.Schedule.channel.length);
    }
});
```